# Styles is missing after I bundle my project with Vite

Tags: vue.js, vite, rollup

As title, my styles (including style tag in SFC and css imported to `app.ts`) are missing when I compile my app in IIFE format.

I have no idea whether it's by Vite or RollUp... It works properly with `vite serve`, but not `vite build`.

I saw the css emitted in other format, but not `IIFE`. For that, I can't load Vue form CDN, which I want to.

```js
// vite.config.js
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import env from "vite-plugin-env-compatible";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    env({
      prefix: "",
      mountedPath: "process.env",
    }),
    vue(),
  ],
  build: {
    minify: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        format: "iife",
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```js
// src/app.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";

import App from "./App.vue";

import "./main.css";

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<!-- src/App.vue -->
<template>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>

  <button @click="increment">Click Me!</button>
  <div>Clicked: {{ count }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

//#region Counter
const count = ref(0);
const increment = () => (count.value += 1);
//#endregion
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found in documentation, all I need is setting `build.cssCodeSplit` to `false`.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-code-splitting

[Related issue for follow up](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10630)