# Vue3 + Vite CSS styles are different in development and production

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vue 3 app bundle by Vite.
I have a simple Homepage with styles for the homepage defined in the Home.vue,and global styles defined in the main.css file which is in (src/assets/main.css):

The problem i am facing is, the homepage that i have styled in development looks very different in production(the styling is different)

IN DEVELOPMENT:
[image]

In PRODUCTION: (styles are not correct)
[image]

As you can see the development has the correct styles(perfect grid and elements are not overflowing)

I don't know where the problem lies but heres my code.

vite.config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    // minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    // modulePreload: false,
  }
})
```

Home.vue: (dont mind the data fetching and all in the , it just renders tect from an api)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, onBeforeMount, onMounted } from 'vue';
import router from '../../router';
import { useArticlesStore } from '../../stores/articles.js';
import { client } from '../../contentful';

const articlesStore = useArticlesStore();
const spaceID = import.meta.env.VITE_SPACE_ID;
const environmentID = import.meta.env.VITE_ENVIRONMENT_ID;

const blogPoll = ref([])
const selectedAnswer = ref(null);
const selectedPoll = ref(null);
const latestFourArticles = ref([]);
let categoryVotes = ref(0)

const displayedArticles = computed(() => {
  return articlesStore.searchedArticles.length > 0
    ? articlesStore.searchedArticles
    : articlesStore.articles;
});

function voteCountPercentage(updatedEntry, selectedCategory){
    console.log(selectedCategory)
    let votes = 0;
    if(selectedCategory === 'developers') {
        updatedEntry.Developers.options.forEach(entry => votes += entry.votes)
    }
    else if(selectedCategory === 'gaming') {
        updatedEntry.Gaming.options.forEach(entry => votes += entry.votes)
    }
    else {
        updatedEntry.Tech.options.forEach(entry => votes += entry.votes)
    }
    categoryVotes.value = votes;
}

//here we update the votes of a selected answer by:
//1. getting the selected answer(option) by id
//2. updating its vote number by 1(+1)
//3. and based on the selected answers category(provided on the pollEntry variable(object) e.g Developers, Gaming, Tech), we update the poll answer(option
// * and OPTIONALLY, we set the width of the selected poll(by percentage) for styling purposes
function selectAnswer(answerID, answerIndex, pollID, question, answer, poll) {
  selectedAnswer.value = answerID;
  selectedPoll.value = pollID;
  let selectedCategory;

  //we get the selected topic by using the object answer ...in array
  client.getSpace(spaceID)
 .then((space) => space.getEnvironment('master'))
  .then((environment) => environment.getEntry(environmentID))
  .then((entry) => {
    let pollEntry = entry.fields.poll['en-US'];
    let pollEntryCategoryToUpdate = pollEntry.Developers.question === poll.question ? pollEntry.Developers : pollEntry.Gaming.question === poll.question ? pollEntry.Gaming : pollEntry.Tech;
    let selectedPollEntryToUpdate = pollEntryCategoryToUpdate.options[answerIndex];
    selectedPollEntryToUpdate.votes = selectedPollEntryToUpdate.votes + 1;

    if(pollEntry.Developers.question === pollEntryCategoryToUpdate.question){
        // console.log('developers')
        // console.log(entry.fields.poll['en-US'])
        selectedCategory = 'developers';
        entry.fields.poll['en-US'].Developers.options[answerIndex] = selectedPollEntryToUpdate;
    } else if (pollEntry.Gaming.question === pollEntryCategoryToUpdate.question) {
        selectedCategory = 'gaming';
        entry.fields.poll['en-US'].Gaming.options[answerIndex] = selectedPollEntryToUpdate;
    } else {
        selectedCategory = 'tech';
        entry.fields.poll['en-US'].Tech.options[answerIndex] = selectedPollEntryToUpdate;
    }

    return entry.update()
  })
  .then((entry) => {
    entry.publish();
    console.log(`Entry ${entry.sys.id} updated.`)
    console.log(entry)
    const updatedEntry = entry.fields.poll['en-US'];
    voteCountPercentage(updatedEntry, selectedCategory)
  })

}

function fetchArticle(id) {
    router.push(`/read-article/${id}`)
}

onBeforeMount(() => {
    articlesStore.clearSearchArticles();
})

//fetch all articles from CMS
onMounted(async () => {
    const art = await articlesStore.fetchAllArticles();
    const pollQuestions = articlesStore.pollQuestions.poll;
    const { Developers, Gaming, Tech } = pollQuestions;

    const poll = [Developers, Gaming, Tech];
    blogPoll.value = poll;
    const fourArticles = art.filter((article) => article.id > 1);
    latestFourArticles.value = fourArticles
})
</script>

<template>
  <Navbar/>  
  <main id="home-wrapper">
    <!-- LATEST 5 ARTICLES / Top of the month -->
    <section id="latest-articles">
        <div class="main-latest">
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <img :src="articlesStore.articles[0].img" alt="" class="article-image">
          <p class="title main-title">{{ articlesStore.articles[0].title }}</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="sub-latest" v-if="articlesStore.articles.length  > articlesStore.articles.length - 1">
            <div class="sub-article" v-for="(article, index) in latestFourArticles">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img :src="article.img ? article.img : ''" alt="" class="latest-article-img">
                <p class="title">{{ article.title }}</p> 
                <p class="article-date">{{ article.date }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div id="heading-wrapper">
       <h2 id="new-articles-heading">New Articles</h2>
       <div class="heading-underline"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- NEW ARTICLES -->
    <section class="all-new-articles">
      <div class="new-article" v-for="article in displayedArticles" @click="fetchArticle(article.id)">
        <img :src="article.img" alt="" class="new-article-img">
        <p class="new-article-title"><span class="span-new-article-title">{{ article.title }}</span></p>
        <p class="date">{{ article.date }}</p>
        <p
          :class="{
            category: true,
            developers: article.category === 'Developers',
            gaming: article.category === 'Gaming',
            tech: article.category === 'Tech'
          }"
        >
          {{ article.category }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div id="heading-wrapper">
       <h2 id="new-articles-heading">POLL'S</h2>
       <div class="heading-underline"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- POLL -->
    <section id="poll">
        <div class="poll-area" v-for="(poll, index) in blogPoll">
            <p class="poll-question">{{ poll.question }}</p>
            <div class="opt" v-for="answer, answerIndex in poll.options" @click="selectAnswer(answer.id, answerIndex,  poll.id, poll.question, answer.answer, poll)">
              <div
               id="percentage"
               v-if="answer.id === selectedAnswer && poll.id === selectedPoll"
               :style="{ 'width' : answer.votes * 100 / categoryVotes + '%' }"
               >
            </div>
              <p class="option-name">{{ answer.answer }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
#home-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#home-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;
    background-color: none;
}

#home-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ed1d3c41;
    border-radius: 2px;
}


#latest-articles {
    height: 55%;
    display: flex;
}

.article-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.main-latest {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .4s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-latest:hover, .main-latest img {
    transform: scale(1.008);
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ed1d3b;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(181deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, #ed1d3cad 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(181deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, #ed1d3cad);
    z-index: 2;
}

.sub-latest{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-article{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .4s;
}

.sub-article:hover, .sub-article img {
    transform: scale(1.02);
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 0 5% 3%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.article-date{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0 0 1% 3%;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-title{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#heading-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.heading-underline {
    height: 5px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #ed1d3b;
}

.all-new-articles {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 350px));
    grid-auto-rows: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2%;
    height: 40%;
    max-height: 850px;
    margin: 3% 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.all-new-articles::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background-color: none;
}

.all-new-articles::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ed1d3c41;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.new-article{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0f1010;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ed1d3b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .4s;
}

.new-article:hover {
    transform: scale(1.04);
}

.latest-article-img{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.new-article-title, .date, .category {
    padding-left: 3%;
    line-height: 2.5;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.category {
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.developers, .gaming, .tech {
    padding: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.developers {
    background-color: #ed1d3b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
}

.gaming {
    background-color: #f10de2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #f10de2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #f10de2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #f10de2;
}

.tech {
    background-color: #5d00f9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #5d00f9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #5d00f9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #5d00f9;
}


#poll {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 350px));
    grid-auto-rows: 100%;
    gap: 3.5%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 3% 0;
}
.poll-area {
    max-width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 700px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    background-color: #0f1010;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.poll-question {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background: #242526;
    padding: 2%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.65rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.opt {
    position: relative;
    margin: 4.2% 4.2% 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 1px solid #ed1d3b;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .4s;
    height: 10%;
}

.opt:hover {
    transform: scale(1.02);
}

.option-name {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

#percentage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ed1d3b;
    z-index: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .all-new-articles {
        height: 50%;
    }
    .developers, .gaming, .tech {
    padding: 0% 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-latest {
        display: none;
    }

    .sub-latest {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #new-articles-heading {
        font-size: 1.9rem;
    }

    /* #poll {
        height: 40%;
    } */

    .poll-question {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .option-name {
        font-size: 0.7rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    
    .new-article-title {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 1.05rem !important;
        bottom: 3.5%;
    }

    .developers, .gaming{
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 2%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
    }

    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #poll {
        height: 55%;
    }

    .poll-area {
        max-height: 450px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .poll-question {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .main-title {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    #poll {
        height: 55%;
    }
    .poll-area {
        max-width: 385px;
    }
}

</style>
```

main.css:

```
:root {
  --vt-c-white: #ffffff;
  --vt-c-white-soft: #f8f8f8;
  --vt-c-white-mute: #f2f2f2;

  --vt-c-black: #181818;
  --vt-c-black-soft: #222222;
  --vt-c-black-mute: #282828;

  --vt-c-indigo: #2c3e50;

  --vt-c-divider-light-1: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.29);
  --vt-c-divider-light-2: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.12);
  --vt-c-divider-dark-1: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.65);
  --vt-c-divider-dark-2: rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.48);

  --vt-c-text-light-1: var(--vt-c-indigo);
  --vt-c-text-light-2: rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.66);
  --vt-c-text-dark-1: var(--vt-c-white);
  --vt-c-text-dark-2: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.64);
}

/* semantic color variables for this project */
:root {
  --color-background: var(--vt-c-white);
  --color-background-soft: var(--vt-c-white-soft);
  --color-background-mute: var(--vt-c-white-mute);

  --color-border: var(--vt-c-divider-light-2);
  --color-border-hover: var(--vt-c-divider-light-1);

  --color-heading: var(--vt-c-text-light-1);
  --color-text: var(--vt-c-text-light-1);

  --section-gap: 160px;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --color-background: var(--vt-c-black);
    --color-background-soft: var(--vt-c-black-soft);
    --color-background-mute: var(--vt-c-black-mute);

    --color-border: var(--vt-c-divider-dark-2);
    --color-border-hover: var(--vt-c-divider-dark-1);

    --color-heading: var(--vt-c-text-dark-1);
    --color-text: var(--vt-c-text-dark-2);
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html{
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
}

#app{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#app::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.1px;
  background-color: none;
}

#app::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ed1d3c41;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* STYLES APPLICABLE TO NAVIGAITON PAGES DISPLAY ARTICLES */
#heading-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #heading-wrapper {
    margin: 7.5% auto;
  }
}

#new-articles-heading{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 0.5% 0;
}

#new-articles-heading-read {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 0.5% 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #new-articles-heading{
    font-size: 1.9rem;
  }

  #new-articles-heading-read {
    font-size: 1.55rem;
  }
}

.heading-underline {
  height: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #ed1d3b;
}


.all-new-articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 350px));
  grid-auto-rows: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2%;
  height: 40%;
  max-height: 850px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  margin: 1% 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .all-new-articles {
    height: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .rtc-paragraph {
    margin: 5% 0 !important;
  }

  .rtc-img-wrapper {
    max-height: 450px !important;
  }
}

.new-article{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #0f1010;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ed1d3b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .4s;
}

.new-article:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

.new-article-img{
  display: block;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.new-article-title, .date, .category {
  padding-left: 3%;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.category {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline;
  width: 31%;
}

.developers, .gaming, .tech {
  padding-left: 2%;
  margin-left: 3%;
}


.developers, {
  background-color: #ed1d3b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #ed1d3b;
}

.gaming {
  background-color: #f10de2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #f10de2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #f10de2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #f10de2;
}

.tech {
  background-color: #5d00f9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #5d00f9;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #5d00f9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px 1.5px #5d00f9;
}

/*STYLES FOR THE READ ARTICLES PAGE ARE DEFINED HERE BECAUSE THE RICH TEXT EDITOR OF THE CMS MUST HAVE ITS STYLES GLOBAL TO THE HTML PAGE*/
.article-content {
  max-width: 1550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rtc-paragraph {
  margin: 1% 0;
}

.rtc-img-wrapper {
  height: 750px;
  max-height: 525px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 2% auto;
}

.rtc-img{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .rtc-img-wrapper {
    max-height: 360px;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?
I tried adding [build.cssCodeSplit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5AjD.png) as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74177078/styles-is-missing-after-i-bundle-my-project-with-vite) but no success

Comment: first step is identifying what's actually different which is done by just inspecting the DOM.  Compare dev to production.  The inspector can tell you every CSS property being applied and what stylesheets those properties come from.  It will be very valuable information to figure out what CSS styles are different, as it will lead you to the specific code you need to investigate.  There's way too much right now to reasonably review.